# functional parallelism and laziness in Scala

Tags: scala, concurrency, parallel-processing, functional-programming, lazy-evaluation

## Background

I have been reading the book [Functional Programming in Scala](https://www.manning.com/books/functional-programming-in-scala), and have some questions regarding the content in [Chapter 7: Purely functional parallelism](https://github.com/fpinscala/fpinscala/wiki/Chapter-7:-Purely-functional-parallelism).

Here is the code for the answers in the book: [Par.scala](https://github.com/fpinscala/fpinscala/blob/master/answers/src/main/scala/fpinscala/parallelism/Par.scala), but I am confused about certain part of it.

Here is the first part of the code of `Par.scala`, which stands for ***Parallelism***:

```
import java.util.concurrent._

object Par {
  type Par[A] = ExecutorService => Future[A]

  def unit[A](a: A): Par[A] = (es: ExecutorService) => UnitFuture(a)

  private case class UnitFuture[A](get: A) extends Future[A] {
    def isDone = true
    def get(timeout: Long, units: TimeUnit): A = get
    def isCancelled = false
    def cancel(evenIfRunning: Boolean): Boolean = false
  }

  def map2[A, B, C](a: Par[A], b: Par[B])(f: (A, B) => C): Par[C] =
    (es: ExecutorService) => {
      val af = a(es)
      val bf = b(es)
      UnitFuture(f(af.get, bf.get))
    }

  def fork[A](a: => Par[A]): Par[A] =
    (es: ExecutorService) => es.submit(new Callable[A] {
      def call: A = a(es).get
    })

  def lazyUnit[A](a: => A): Par[A] =
    fork(unit(a))

  def run[A](es: ExecutorService)(a: Par[A]): Future[A] = a(es)

  def asyncF[A, B](f: A => B): A => Par[B] =
    a => lazyUnit(f(a))

  def map[A, B](pa: Par[A])(f: A => B): Par[B] =
    map2(pa, unit(()))((a, _) => f(a))
}
```

- The simplest possible model for `Par[A]` might be `ExecutorService => Future[A]`, and `run` simply returns the `Future`.
- `unit` promotes a constant value to a parallel computation by returning a `UnitFuture`, which is a simple implementation of `Future` that just wraps a constant value.
- `map2` combines the results of two parallel computations with a binary function.
- `fork` marks a computation for concurrent evaluation. The evaluation won’t actually occur until forced by run. Here is with its simplest and most natural implementation of it. Even though it has its problems, let's first put them aside.
- `lazyUnit` wraps its unevaluated argument in a `Par` and marks it for concurrent evaluation.
- `run` extracts a value from a `Par` by actually performing the computation.
- `asyncF` converts any function `A => B` to one that evaluates its result asynchronously.

---

## Questions

The `fork` is the function confuses me a lot here, because it takes a ***lazy argument***, which will be evaluated later when it is called. Then my questions are more about when we should use this `fork`, i.e., when we need lazy-evaluation and when we need to have the value directly.

Here is an exercise from the book:

> EXERCISE 7.5
> *Hard*: Write this function, called sequence. No additional primitives are required. Do not call run.
>
> `def sequence[A](ps: List[Par[A]]): Par[List[A]]`

And here is the answers (offered [here](https://github.com/fpinscala/fpinscala/blob/master/answers/src/main/scala/fpinscala/parallelism/Par.scala)).

---

**First**

```
  def sequence_simple[A](l: List[Par[A]]): Par[List[A]] =
    l.foldRight[Par[List[A]]](unit(List()))((h, t) => map2(h, t)(_ :: _))
```

What is the different between above code and the following:

```
  def sequence_simple[A](l: List[Par[A]]): Par[List[A]] =
    l.foldLeft[Par[List[A]]](unit(List()))((t, h) => map2(h, t)(_ :: _))
```

---

**Additionally**

```
  def sequenceRight[A](as: List[Par[A]]): Par[List[A]] =
    as match {
      case Nil => unit(Nil)
      case h :: t => map2(h, fork(sequenceRight(t)))(_ :: _)
    }

  def sequenceBalanced[A](as: IndexedSeq[Par[A]]): Par[IndexedSeq[A]] = fork {
    if (as.isEmpty) unit(Vector())
    else if (as.length == 1) map(as.head)(a => Vector(a))
    else {
      val (l,r) = as.splitAt(as.length/2)
      map2(sequenceBalanced(l), sequenceBalanced(r))(_ ++ _)
    }
  }
```

In `sequenceRight`, `fork` is used when recursive function is directly called. However, in `sequenceBalanced`, `fork` is used outside of the whole function body.

Then, what is the differences or above code and the following (where we switched the places of `fork`):

```
  def sequenceRight[A](as: List[Par[A]]): Par[List[A]] = fork {
    as match {
      case Nil => unit(Nil)
      case h :: t => map2(h, sequenceRight(t))(_ :: _)
    }
  }

  def sequenceBalanced[A](as: IndexedSeq[Par[A]]): Par[IndexedSeq[A]] =
    if (as.isEmpty) unit(Vector())
    else if (as.length == 1) map(as.head)(a => Vector(a))
    else {
      val (l,r) = as.splitAt(as.length/2)
      map2(fork(sequenceBalanced(l)), fork(sequenceBalanced(r)))(_ ++ _)
    }
```

---

**Finally**, given the `sequence` defined above, we have the following function:

```
  def parMap[A,B](ps: List[A])(f: A => B): Par[List[B]] = fork {
    val fbs: List[Par[B]] = ps.map(asyncF(f))
    sequence(fbs)
  }
```

I would like to know, can I also implement the function in the following way, which is by applying the `lazyUnit` defined in the beginning? Is this implementation `lazyUnit(ps.map(f))` lazy?

```
  def parMapByLazyUnit[A, B](ps: List[A])(f: A => B): Par[List[B]] =
    lazyUnit(ps.map(f))
```

Answer (score 1):

I did not completely understand your doubt. But I see a major problem with the following solution,

```
def parMapByLazyUnit[A, B](ps: List[A])(f: A => B): Par[List[B]] =
  lazyUnit(ps.map(f))
```

To understand the problem lets look at `def lazyUnit`,

```
def fork[A](a: => Par[A]): Par[A] =
  (es: ExecutorService) => es.submit(new Callable[A] {
    def call: A = a(es).get
  })

def lazyUnit[A](a: => A): Par[A] =
  fork(unit(a))
```

So... `lazyUnit` takes an expression of type `=> A` and submits it to `ExecutorService` to get evaluated. And returns the wrapped result of this parallel computation as `Par[A]`.

In `parMap` for every element of `ps: List[A]`, we not only have to evaluate the corresponding mapping using the function `f: A => B` but we have to do these evaluations `in parallel`.

But our solution `lazyUnit(ps.map(f))` will submit the whole `{ ps.map(f) }` evaluation as a single task to our `ExecutionService`. Which means we are not doing it in parallel.

What we need to do is make sure that for each element `a` in `ps: [A]`, the function `f: A => B` is executed as a separate task for our `ExecutorService`.

Now, as we learned from our implementation is that we can run an expression of type `exp: => A` by using `lazyUnit(exp)` to get a `result: Par[A]`.

So, we will do exactly that for every `a: A` in `ps: List[A]`,

```
val parMappedTmp = ps.map( a => lazyUnit(f(a) ) )

// or

val parMappedTmp = ps.map( a => asyncF(f)(a) )

// or

val parMappedTmp = ps.map(asyncF(f))
```

But, Now our `parMappedTmp` is a `List[Par[B]]` and whereas we needed a `Par[List[B]]`

So, you will need a function with the following signature to get what you wanted,

```
def sequence[A](ps: List[Par[A]]): Par[List[A]]
```

Once you have it,

```
val parMapped = sequence(parMappedTmp)
```

Comment: I don't think you have to put `() => f(a)` instead of `f(a)` for a lazy argument. For example, a function like `def f(p: => Int, eval : Boolean) = if (eval) println(p)`, you can call if like `f(3/0, false)`, instead of `f(() => 3/0, false)`

Comment: I think this is the purpose of lazy argument evaluation.

Comment: Yup. I think you are correct about that. But rest of the explanation still holds.

Comment: could you please modify the first part of your answer? then let's further discuss the rest and try to make it clear.

Comment: Thanks.   Your answer answered my **Finally** question.   Could you please also address the **First** and **Additionally** questions?